# Function to Set Product type in Woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add a subscription product with custom function in WooCommerce. I am able to add a simple product along with the `post_meta`, but unable to set the `product_type` for that product.

Does anyone know the function for saving `product_type` in WooCommerce?

Comment: Unbelievable! How could this question be off-topic??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured this out, to set the [`product_type`](https://bobwp.com/woocommerce-product-types-tutorial/), instead of using [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta), you use:

> wp_set_object_terms( $productID, 'subscription', 'product_type' );

Answer (score 0):

So I had a look in the wp-terms table.
I needed to be able to determine product type from an SQL perspective.
Specifically to distinguish between variable and simple product types.

Then you have to do battle with the wp_term_relationships and wp_term_taxonomy tables to link it all together. This is more a blues clue than a full solution.
I have not written an SQL statement that pulls it all together as yet.

Comment: Sharing codes backing your answer is always a good practice here and surely helps.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but may be useful for new searchs:
Product type is stored in wp_term_relationship. You can find in the table wp_terms the names "simple, grouped, variable, etc", and get their term_id.

Here is a SQL example I used to set all products already set to variable (10) to simple (8):

```
UPDATE wp_term_relationships
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON(wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID)
SET wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 8
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product'
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 10
```